# Como calcular o valor total considerando determinado atributo como parametro de incremento ou decremento?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha em excel onde são registradas ações de compra (C) e venda (V) na mesma coluna, já em outra coluna tenho os valores negociados.

Exemplo:

```
  Ação |  Valores
  ----------------
    C  |  3.000,00
    C  |  200
    V  |  3.500,00
```

Em uma segunda tabela tenho registros de deposito (D) e saque (S):

```
  Ação  |  Valor
  --------------
    D   |  5.000
    S   |  500
```

Como posso calcular o **saldo** total em carteira considerando que, cada saque (S) ou compra (C) deve decrementar o saldo, já ações de venda (V) ou deposito (D) devem incrementar o saldo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei um exemplo de acordo com as informações que você fez:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A fórmula que está contido na célula `K3`, que representa o **Saldo** atual:

```
=SOMA(C:C;G:G) - ( SOMASES(C:C;B:B;"C") + SOMASES(G:G;F:F;"S") )
```

Onde somo todos os valores e decremento de acordo com as Compras(C) e Saques(S)